# Populating a list/array by index in Python?

Tags: python, list

Is this possible:

```
myList = []

myList[12] = 'a'
myList[22] = 'b'
myList[32] = 'c'
myList[42] = 'd'
```

When I try, I get:

```
# IndexError: list assignment index out of range #
```

Comment: myList = () is actual a tuple, you can't add, remove or find objects in a tuple.

Comment: Yeah I actually used [] in the code, got mixed up here.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You'll have to pre-fill it with something (e.g. `0` or `None`) before you can index it:

```
myList = [None] * 100  # Create list of 100 'None's
myList[12] = 'a'  # etc.
```

Alternatively, use a dict instead of a list, as [Alex Martelli suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869778/populating-a-list-array-by-index-in-python/869805#869805).

Answer (score 29):

For a "sparse list" you could use a `dict` instead:

```
mylist = {}
mylist[12] = 'a'
```

etc.  If you want an actual list (initialize it with `[]`, *not* `()`, of course!-) you need to fill the un-set slots to _some_thing, e.g. `None`, by a little auxiliary function or by subclassing `list`.

Comment: Judging by the error, I believe he was actually using a list, not a tuple.

Comment: it probably won't be the best practice to call your dictionary `mylist`.

Comment: Thanks I need linear access to the item, so I will be able to index from 1 to n, so can't use dictionary.

Comment: Sure you can, there are plenty of ways to do that with a dict.  i.e. "for k in sorted(mydict.keys()): print mydict[k]"

Comment: Indexing from 1 to n in the dictionary still works.  `for i in range(n): if n in dictionary: print dictionary[n]` does what you want.

Comment: wouldn't giving a dict a numeric index be a bit counter intuitive for anyone else working with the code though

Comment: The dict will not be in order when you loop through.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a quick list wrapper that will auto-expand your list with zeros if you attempt to assign a value to a index past it's length.

```
class defaultlist(list):

   def __setitem__(self, index, value):
      size = len(self)
      if index >= size:
         self.extend(0 for _ in range(size, index + 1))

      list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
```

Now you can do this:

```
>>> a = defaultlist([1,2,3])
>>> a[1] = 5
[1,5,3]
>>> a[5] = 10
[1,5,3,0,0,10]
```

Comment: Note too that @Pithikos expands this to a list of arbitrary dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Not without populating the other locations in the list with something (like `None` or an empty string).  Trying to insert an element into a list using the code you wrote would result in an `IndexError`.

There's also `mylist.insert`, but this code:

```
myList.insert(12,'a')
```

would just insert 'a' at the first unoccupied location in the list (which would be 0 using your example).

So, as I said, there has to be something in the list at indexes 0-11 before you can insert something at `myList[12]`.

Comment: Indeed, list.insert() is not a correct solution, since inserting an item will move every other indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the size of the list ahead of time, you could use try/except and then Extend the list in the except:

```
L = []
def add(i, s):
    try:
        L[i] = s
    except IndexError:
        L.extend([None]*(i-len(L)+1))
        L[i] = s

add(12, 'a')
add(22, 'b')
```

**----- Update ---------------------------------------------**
Per tgray's comment: If it is likely that your code will throw an Exception *most of the time*, you should check the length of the List every time, and avoid the Exceptions:

```
L = []
def add(i, s):
    size = len(L)
    if i >= size:
        L.extend([None]*(i-size+1))
        L[i] = s
```

Comment: If he is adding items with increasing indexes, the speed could probably be improved by using an 'if' statement instead of a 'try-catch'.  In this case you would be catching the exception every time, which is more "expensive" than checking the length of L every time.

Comment: Do you have a link to source stating it is more "expensive"? Or by how much? That would be helpful.

Comment: Here's a link to the source of my comment: http://paltman.com/2008/jan/18/try-except-performance-in-python-a-simple-test/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs, I figured out a soluction for my problem, I needed to **calc a lot of factorials**, some of them **could be repeated**, so here is my solution:

```
factorials = {}

def calcFact(v):
    try:
        return factorials[v]
    except KeyError:
        factorials[v] = math.factorial(v)
        return factorials[v]
```

**Testcase:**

```
calcFact(99000)
calcFact(90900)
calcFact(90090)
calcFact(90009)
calcFact(90009) #repeated
calcFact(90009) #repeated
```

**Results:**

> Repeating mathematical calc: **1.576** s
>
> Using the above code (a list to store repeated values): **1.011** s

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @phineas as I said in my answer, this was something that I needed to solve, and that was related with "Populating a list/array by index" as you can notice by reading the code. This is way to solve the question, but with a different example.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of Triptych.. If you want a list of arbitrary dimensions

```
class dynamiclist(list):
    """ List not needing pre-initialization

    Example:
        l = dynamiclist()
        l[20][1] = 10
        l[21][1] = 20
    """

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        size = len(self)
        if index >= size:
            self.extend(dynamiclist() for _ in range(size, index + 1))

        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        size = len(self)
        if index >= size:
            self.extend(dynamiclist() for _ in range(size, index + 1))  # allows dimensions > 1

        return list.__getitem__(self, index)
```

Example

```
l = dynamiclist()
l[20][1] = 10
l[21][1] = 20
```